# How to get facebook comments with Java?

Tags: java, facebook, get, comments

I can access facebook public posts and get them. But i couldn't get the comments with them. Here is part of my code :

```
facebook.setOAuthAppId("1**********", "S*** S***");
    facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken("bla bla bla", null));

    try{

    int counter=0;

    ResponseList<Post> results = facebook.searchPosts("galatasaray", new Reading().limit(100));
    for(Post post : results){
    System.out.println();
//      PagableList<Comment> comments=post.getComments();
//      for(Comment comment : comments){
//      System.out.println(comment.getMessage());
//      }
    counter++;

    System.out.println("NAME:-->>>" + post.getName());
    System.out.println("DATE:-->>>" + post.getCreatedTime());
    System.out.println("MESSAGE:-->>>" + post.getMessage());        
    System.out.println("NAME2:-->>>" + post.getFrom().getName());
    System.out.println("URL--->>>"+post.getLink());
    System.out.println("COUNT:-->>>" + counter);
    System.out.println("ID-------->>>"+post.getId());
    System.out.println("Comments----->>> ");

    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
```

Comment: I have no idea how the facebook api works but [[here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)] is something said about fields and permission and and [[here](http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html#paging)] is and example how you read them.

Comment: thanks for reply but i've already read them all.

Comment: What happens when you don't get the comments? Is there an exception or some warning logged somewhere or is the result just null / empty list? Also have you confirmed that those posts you get have comments? I've played with [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dgalatasaray%26type%3Dpost) a bit and it seems that most posts simply have no `"comments": {`.

Comment: But that galatasaray word was just an example. What if I use it with another popular word like a bank name ? I'm working on a complaint management program. All I need is getting users's comments.

Comment: It doesn't return anything when I try to get comments btw.